# Can't use ADO.NET Entity Data Model in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project but can't use in class or `Default.aspx.vb`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i build and rebuild Several times but still cant use model.

Comment: open Model.Designer.vb and see the name of the class. Then, try to use Ctrl + '.' to import the correct namespace.

Comment: here is model.designer.vb code:  ' Default code generation is disabled for model 'C:\Users\Meysam\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Code\Model.edmx'. 
' To enable default code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
' property to an alternate value. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model is
' open in the designer.

Comment: i think namespace is :MyDataBaseModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
i change `Code Generation Strategy` from `None` to `Default` then build project. now i can use  `Dim db As New MyDataBaseModel.MyDataBaseEntities`